# How to unify jQuery image script?

Tags: jquery

my english langueage is not good. sorry!

i want to have one script for all images in body.

my scripts is clone images to figure and clone "image alt" to figcaption.

this is two script for two image. and i want one script for all any images.

I hope to have written it correctly and i hope fixed my problem.

I want unify = 1.ins,inm,.. 2.#fig 3.#figcapt

thanks

```js
$("img").removeAttr("height");
$('.ins, .inm, .inl, .outs, .outm, .outl').each(function(i) {
 var $this = $(this);
 var newClass = "i" + i++;    
    $this.addClass(newClass);
});

// i want unify The following two scripts :

// SCRIPT 1:

$('.ins.i0, .inm.i0, .inl.i0, .outs.i0, .outm.i0, .outl.i0').each(function() {
 var $repi = $(this);
 var repicl = $(this).attr("class");
  $repi.after("<figure id='fig0'></figure>");
  $('#fig0').addClass(repicl);
  $repi.clone().appendTo("#fig0");
  $("#fig0").append("<figcaption id='fcapt0' class='fcapt'></figcaption>");
 var $alti =  $(this).attr('alt');
 $("#fcapt0").html($alti);
 $(this).remove();
 return false;

});

// SCRIPT 2:

$('.ins.i1, .inm.i1, .inl.i1, .outs.i1, .outm.i1, .outl.i1').each(function() {
 var $repi = $(this);
 var repicl = $(this).attr("class");
  $repi.after("<figure id='fig1'></figure>");
  $('#fig1').addClass(repicl);
  $repi.clone().appendTo("#fig1");
  $("#fig1").append("<figcaption id='fcapt1' class='fcapt'></figcaption>");
 var $alti =  $(this).attr('alt');
 $("#fcapt1").html($alti);

 $(this).remove();
 return false;

});
```

```css
figure{
 margin: auto;
 padding:auto; 
 float: inherit;
 height:auto !important;
 position: relative;
 
}
figure.inm{
 width:50% !important;
 margin:0;
 padding:0; 
}
figure.inl{
 width:75% !important;
 margin:0;
 padding:0; 
}
figure.ins img, figure.inm img, figure.inl img{
 width:100% !important;
 margin:0;
 padding:0; 
}
figure.ins{
 width:33.3% !important;
 margin:0;
 padding:0; 
}
figure.size-full{
 margin:10px 10px 0px 10px !important;
 padding:0 !important;

}
figure.alignnone, figure.alignright  {
 float: right;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
figure.alignleft   {
 float: left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
figure figcaption{
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #000;
 color: #fff;
 opacity: 0.5;
 width: 97%;
 bottom: 13px;
 right: 0;
 height: auto;
 padding:0 1.5% 0 1.5%;
 line-height: 180%;
 font-size: 9pt;
 margin: 0;
 text-align: right;

}

figure:hover figcaption{
 display: none
}
body img{
 max-width:100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>aaaaaaa</p>
<p><img class="inm alignright wp-image-2414 size-full" src="bbbbbb.jpg" alt="bbbbbb" width="287" height="176" /></p>
<p>cccccccccc</p>
<p>ddddddddd</p>
<p><img class="inm alignleft wp-image-2425 size-full" src="eeeeeee.jpg" alt="eeee " width="271" height="186" /></p>
<p>ffffffff</p>
<p>gggggggggg</p>
<p>hhhhhhhhhhhh</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `i` as class, then do all actions dynamically based on `i` like below. Also I optimize your code and removed some extra. Also I used `wrap` instead of clone and remove elements.

```js
$('.inm').each(function(i) {

  var $this = $(this);
  $this.addClass("i" + i);
    
  var repicl = $this.attr("class");
  var $alti = $this.attr('alt');

  $this.wrap("<figure id='fig"+i+"' class='"+repicl+"'></figure>");
  $("#fig" + i).append("<figcaption id='fcapt"+i+"' class='fcapt'>"+$alti+"</figcaption>");
  
});
```

```css
figure {
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
  float: inherit;
  height: auto !important;
  position: relative;
}

figure.inm {
  width: 50% !important;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

figure.inl {
  width: 75% !important;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

figure.ins img,
figure.inm img,
figure.inl img {
  width: 100% !important;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

figure.ins {
  width: 33.3% !important;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

figure.size-full {
  margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

figure.alignnone,
figure.alignright {
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

figure.alignleft {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

figure figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 97%;
  bottom: 13px;
  right: 0;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0 1.5% 0 1.5%;
  line-height: 180%;
  font-size: 9pt;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

figure:hover figcaption {
  display: none
}

body img {
  max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img class="inm" alt="Some alt text" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1446292267125-fecb4ecbf1a5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" />

<img class="inm" alt="Some alt text" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1446292267125-fecb4ecbf1a5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" />
```

Comment: @ramin glad to help